# Python match tuples in string

Tags: python, regex, string, tuples

I have a string with the format:

```
s = "[(1,2,'foe'), (3,5,'bar'), ...]"
```

I need to extract each tuple using regular expressions.

I tried stripping `'['` and `']'` and then apply

```
re.findall(r'\((\d+),(\d+),(.+)\)', s[1:-1])
```

and other variants but cannot make it work.

Comment: N.B: This pattern is not recursive, it's repeating. A recursive one would be like:
`[(1, [(2, [(3, [...])])])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a list-literal. You don't evaluate those with regex, you throw `ast.literal_eval` on it and are done.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("[(1,2,'foe'), (3,5,'bar')]")
[(1, 2, 'foe'), (3, 5, 'bar')]
```

Comment: thats exactly what I needed!! Thanks very much. Sorry I didn't know about ast module.